# Is it possible to have a media folder inside a .nomedia folder?

Tags: file-system, media-files, media-scanner, media-search

I have a folder with various folders and subfolders where I don't want my content to be scanned.

Inside that folder I have put a .nomedia file to prevent media scanning.

Now, **I have a single folder (with music) what I do it to get scanned**.

Is it possible to do something like writing a ".media" file or setting an exception on the .nomedia file?

Comment: Why don't you just take out the folder that you want to be scanned, and put it in a different location?

Comment: Because that would inviabilize my folder structure and force me to look into private and public folder trees when her I want to look at all files. My solution was to define on each subfolder whether it is or not a .nomedia. Not a perfect solution because I'll have to add nomedia files whenever I create new folders and because I always have to create multiple files on multiple subfolders of public folders. But I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I get him now. If the .nomedia file exists in a folder containing the folders you have it will hide files in all those directories. For example having a .nomedia on /sdcard will definitely hide the whole sd card media. So ensure the folder you want media scanned isn't preceding the folder you don't want media scanned. Like:

```
/sdcard/myfiles/mediapublic/photos
/sdcard/myfiles/mediaprivate/photos
```

These are two folders. To hide media in mediaprivate and photos. Paste the .nomedia file in the mediaprivate directory. If it's photos folder only. Paste it there only. And ensure to remove the file from the folder containing that folder. There is another alternative you can use. Delete all .nomedia files. The folder you want hidden, just start it's name with a dot. Like

```
/sdcard/.myfiles/mediapublic/photos
```

To hide all myfiles

```
/sdcard/myfiles/mediaprivate/.photos
```

To hide only photos

Remember the .nomedia file is an empty file with no code even if you open it with text editor. It is 0bytes size and 0characters. So forget about editing it

Comment: In the future, you should edit your first answer instead of adding a new one

Comment: Thank you for your answer(s). This was not the solution I was hoping for. But apparently it is the the only one... What so have done was remove the nomedia file from the top folder and apply selectively to lower level folders.

Comment: Welcome always.